# how to read the Inner arrays data of JSON?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON as shown below

```
var json = [
    {
        "toppings": []
    },
    {
        "crustings": [
            {
                "crust_name": "kool crust ttttt"

            },
            {
                "crust_name": "vcxvxvx"

            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I am trying to read the names of each toppings and crustings this way

When i tried this way i am getting

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in browser console .

```
for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++)
{
    var topp = json[i].toppings;
    var crust = json[i].crustings;

    alert(crust.length);

}
```

Could you please let me know how do i read the Inner arrays data ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop here is counter-productive due to your JSON structure. `toppings` is part of `json[0]` and `crustings` is on `json[1]`.

```
var topp = json[0].toppings;
var crust = json[1].crustings;

alert(crust.length);
```

To get the behaviour your code implies (which would be a better pattern) you need to include both properties in a single object within the parent:

```
var json = [{
    "toppings": [],
    "crustings": [
        { "crust_name": "kool crust ttttt" }, 
        { "crust_name": "vcxvxvx" }
    ]
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your first item contains "toppings" but no "crustings"; your second item contains "crustings" but not "toppings". So whenever you try to access one non-existing element, it crashes your code. You should always have "toppings" and "crustings" defined, even if they are empty.

```
var json = [
    {
        "toppings": [],
        "crustings": []
    },
    {
        "toppings": [],
        "crustings": [
            {
                "crust_name": "kool crust ttttt"

            },
            {
                "crust_name": "vcxvxvx"

            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrTopping = json[0].toppings;
var arrCrusting = [];
var arrCrustingsTemp = json[1].crustings;
arrCrustingsTemp.forEach(function(i){
  arrCrusting.push(i.crust_name);
});
```

Now `arrTopping` contains toppings and `arrCrusting` contains crusting.